# How to efficiently detect changes in an array that changes over time

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, queue, reactive-programming

I intend to continuously poll a couple of endpoints where I receive an array of objects as JSON. These objects are  bound to change over time and each has a unique id. I want to observe for any new object in the array efficiently (one or more objects may have been replaced by a new object). I want to **avoid** looping through the entire array and comparing the id's to the previous array's id's that I saved to some database, this is because the new object may be towards the end of the array and I would be wasting time running all those comparisons.

How would I approach such a scenario? E.g. using some sort of queue. Is using ReactiveX (RXJS) ideal in such a situation?

I am working in Node.js for the implementation.

Comment: If endpoints can set a flag if smth changed then theres that. If you're conflicted about n^2 array comparison, then there're hashmaps, otherwise I cant think of any other way to know if smth changed. You could calculate some kind of hash of entire json, but it's unlikely to be faster than comparing to hashmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RXJS is a good solution, ideal if you don't want to bother with the implementation.

Alternatively you can use the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) (hint, use an EventEmitter to listen to changes), go one this path if you like to have ownership over the code and implementation.

Last alternative is to use a npm module (like [this](https://github.com/medikoo/observable-array#readme)). This seems to follow the Observer Design Pattern. But you can use it as well as inspiration for your own implementation.

But the quickest would be probably to go with RxJs.